Pade discretization for the first derivative
I am looking for the coefficients a,alpha,beta,gamma for highest possible order of first derivative approximation in the following scheme. $u_x$ denotes first derivative with respect to $x$ and $i$ denotes the point $i$.
$a (\frac{\partial u}{\partial x})_{i-1}+ (\frac{\partial u}{\partial x})_{i} +  (\frac{\partial u}{\partial x})_{i+1} = \frac{ \alpha  u_{i-1}+ \beta u_{i}+ \gamma u_{i+1}} {\Delta{x}}$
doing Taylor series expansion on both sides I get on the left hand side
$(2a+1) (u_x)_{i} + a \Delta x^2 (u_{xxx})_{i}$
And on the right hand side
$\frac{(\alpha+\beta+\gamma)} {\Delta x} (u)_{i}+ (\gamma-\alpha) (u_x){_i} + \frac{ (\gamma+\alpha) \Delta x }{ 2}  (u_{xx}){_i} + \frac{ (\gamma-\alpha) \Delta x^2 }{ 6} (u_{xxx})_{i}$
My question is equating the coefficients from both sides, should I say, $a \Delta x^2 = 0 $ or not, as in the r.h.s the third derivative term should not be included or I should say $ a \Delta x^2 = \frac{(\gamma-\alpha) \Delta x^2}{ 6} $ and continue from there.
Thank you so much in advance.

Please use proper math formatting of formulas to make it easier to read your question.

Define truncation error
$$
\tau = Left - Right
$$
and do Taylor expansion to get
$$
\tau = O(1/\Delta x) + O(1) + O(\Delta x) + \ldots
$$
Clearly, for consistency, the $O(1/\Delta x)$ and $O(1)$ term must be zero. Then see how many more of the leading error terms you can kill by choosing your coefficients. Then the first remaining error term will decide the order of accuracy.
